# Window opened using window.open reopens when browser back button is clicked

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I created an asp.net web application which has a linkbutton and hyperlink in the default.aspx. Hyperlink is set navigationurl -"www.google.com". Linkbutton opens the same url in a new tab using javasript's window.open.

Default.aspx

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">Data</asp:LinkButton><br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://www.google.co.in">google</asp:HyperLink>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string url = "http://www.google.com";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('" + url + "');", true);
    }
```

Steps to reproduce my query:
1. Clicks LinkButton. This opens google in new window/tab.
2. Click Hyperlink. This navigates to google. 
3. Click Browser Back button.
This time the browser navigates back to default.aspx, simultaneously google opens in new window/tab.
T want this not to happen.

Comment: instead of using the Click event and an Hyperlink, why don't you put a simple <a> instead of the hyperlink, and define onclick="window.open(....)"?

Comment: Much easier you can create anchor tag and add target="_blank" attribute which will open link in new window.

Comment: I cant add <a> coz originally i have many checking before opening the url in new window.

Answer (score 0):

here's the code: add the code to the page which you don't want the user to return using back.

if(history.length>0)
history.go(+1);

call it on body load

basically i increment the browser history.

Answer (score 0):

Add this codefunction in your head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myfun() {

            window.open("http://www.google.co.in");
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

and in your body

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return myfun();">Data</asp:LinkButton><br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://www.google.co.in">google</asp:HyperLink>
```

**Note:** Avoid any request to server until and unless its not required,you can also do the same with the help of `<a>` tag by keeping `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 0):

Use Hyperlink Button instead of link button and use `target="_blank"` and `url ="www.google.com"` this will open url in new window
No need to use java script to open a new Window .... Also It will Resolve Your Problem

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl="http://www.google.co.in" runat="server"  >Data</asp:HyperLink><br />

<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Target="_self" runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://www.google.co.in">google</asp:HyperLink>
```